# Is there any way to use subtitles with mp3s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3, closed-captions

I have some .mp3 files of conversations with really bad audio quality that I am displaying on a web page using JavaScript. I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to display these mp3s with subtitles.

I came across [this jQuery plugin](http://v2v.cc/~j/jquery.srt/), which does something similar but using the `<video>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). It uses a Timed Text XML file to sync captions. It's free for non-commercial use and reasonably priced for commercial use.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can present mp3 with its subtitles. The problem is.

1. Save the subtitles in the .vvt file format.
2. Create a subtitle box on your web page and
3. write some javascript to show the subtitle as player plays.

And here is an example with an excerpt from the song Hot Stuff:

http://ndfbr.org/danh/music/mp3sub/testmp3.htm